# Разбить переменную с числом на несколько

Tags: bash

Есть переменная, в которой хранится число из двенадцати цифр.

Из этих цифр мне нужно выделить первые четыре цифры в одну переменную, а пятую и шестую цифры — во вторую переменную.

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

например, с помощью [*parameter expansion*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) (см. `man bash`):

```
$ number=212850612345
$ n1=${number:0:4}
$ echo $n1
2128
$ n2=${number:4:2}
$ echo $n2
50
```

синтаксис: `${переменная:смещение:длина}`, где смещение начинается с нуля.

Answer (score 0):

С помощью опции `-c, --characters` у утилиты `cut`, например:

```
$ number="012345678900"
$ first_var=`echo ${number}|cut -c 1-4`
$ 0123
$ second_var=`echo ${number}|cut -c 5,6`
$ 45
```